# Convert list of strings into tuple of integers

Tags: python, string, list, integer, tuples

I need to convert a string of 2 items (separated by a comma) to integers. Also need to switch the list of lists into a tuple of tuples.

from:

`[['0,0'], ['0,1'], ['1,-1'], ['1,0']]`

to:

`((0,0), (0,1), (1,-1), (1,0))`

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mix of map and tuple with list comprehension as:

```
x = [['0,0'], ['0,1'], ['1,-1'], ['1,0']]
x = tuple([tuple(map(int, elt[0].split(','))) for elt in x])
print(x)
```

Output:

```
((0, 0), (0, 1), (1, -1), (1, 0))
```

Explanation: `map` is used to convert the elements to `int` on the output of `split` which is the elements of the inner list. The `tuple` is used to convert the types to `tuple` as required.

Comment: Why is everybody here using advanced solutions? Clearly OP is new to Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard "accumulator pattern":

```py
# Initialize an accumulator
outer_tuple = tuple()

for inner_list in outer_list:
    a, b = inner_list[0].split(",")
    a, b = int(a), int(b)
    outer_tuple += ((a, b),)
```

First, `inner_list[0]` gives the string inside the inner list, e.g.: `"0,1"`. Next,  `.split(",")` splits that string on the comma character, which produces a list of strings: `["0", "1"]`. Then, `a, b = ...` "unpacks" the list into the variables `a` and `b`. Finally, we cast `a` and `b` to `int` and add it as a **tuple of tuples** to the `outer_tuple` (our accumulator).

The reason we need to do `((a, b),)` is because when you add two tuples, you're really just doing a union, or in other words, you're taking the elements from both tuples and creating a new tuple with all the elements:

```py
>>> x = (1, 2)
>>> y = (3, 4)
>>> x + y
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

But that's not what we want. We want a tuple of tuples. Watch what happens:

```py
>>> x += y
>>> x
(1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> x += ((5, 6),)
>>> x
(1, 2, 3, 4, (5, 6))
```

Comment: Note that this code will ONLY work if the input is of the form given in the OP. A more general solution would be in order if you wanted a tuple of 3-tuples, 4-tuples, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

First, we will make a list for the output, then we will iterate through every element in the input list and then make a tupled version of it, the tupled version would be made by spliting the string by the comma and then use the map function to get a tupled version which would have int type rather then string. Then append that to the output List. At last convert the output list into a tuple.

```
inputGiven = [['0,0'], ['0,1'], ['1,-1'], ['1,0']]
outputGivenInList = []
for i in inputGiven:
    tupledVersion = tuple(map(int, i[0].split(",")))
    outputGivenInList.append(tupledVersion)
finalOutput = tuple(outputGivenInList)
print(finalOutput)
```

Comment: FYI, Python is conventionally written using snake_case, not camelCase.

Comment: thanks for the info, I wasn't ever of that fact.

Answer (score -1):

A simple way:

```sh
>>> tmp = tuple(eval(str(li).replace('\'', '')))
>>> ans = (tuple(tmp[i]) for i in range(4))
>>> ans
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x000001754697D8C8>
>>> tuple(ans)
((0, 0), (0, 1), (1, -1), (1, 0))
```